# Misma posición de textos creados mediante geom_text_repel() en varios mapas creados a partir de un bucle

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Tengo un bucle que crea mapas de predicciones para los meses del año. Esto lo creo mediante el lenguaje R, con la libreria ggplot2 y en él incluyo la función geom_text_repel(), la cual no permite que las etiquetas de los puntos que se contienen no se sobrepongan. El problema es que tras cada iteración, las etiquetas de los puntos para cada mapa tienen distintas posiciones, por lo que al crear una presentación de los mapas, se nota más el cambio de posición de dichas etiquetas que de la variabilidad de la predicción como tal y resulta ser desfavorable.
¿Cómo hago que tras la primera iteración del bucle, las posiciones que geom_text_repel() da a cada etiqueta se mantengan para las siguientes iteraciones? Este es el fragmento de mi bucle en el que uso dicha función:

```
#...Código previo...
geom_point(data=ubicaciones, 
           aes(x=X,y=Y), 
           shape=24,
           size=0.6,
           fill="#006400",
           color="#006400") +
geom_text_repel(data=ubicaciones,
                aes(x=X,y=Y,label=Estation),
                color="#006400",
                size=3) + 
#...Código posterior...
```

Estos son ejemplos de mapas creados para dos meses del año:

[image: Mapa 1]
[image: Mapa 2]

Como pueden observar, la posición de las etiquetas o casi de la mayoría cambia tras cada iteración del bucle.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda para solucionar este problema de estética.

Comment: No creo que haya un argumento para fijar la posición con la función `geom_text_repel`, creería que se puede solucionar tu problema haciendo uso de varios `geom_text()`, si mal no me equivoco con 3 o 4 ya no habría superposición. Los ajustas con los argumentos `vjust` o con `hjust`.

Answer (score 0):

`geom_text_repel()` tiene un funcionamiento no determinístico, lo que significa que un mismo gráfico generado en distintas oportunidades generará etiquetas en posiciones distintas, justamente por que estas funciones hacen un cierto número de pruebas al azar para encontrar la mejor combinación de etiquetas que maximicen el objetivo de no superponerse. Ahora bien, esto no significa que no puedas generar una combinación que sea reproducible, el truco para esto, es que justo antes de generar el gráfico o más bien el momento en que eventualmente se evalúa  `geom_text_repel()`, establezcas la "semilla" del generador random, es decir, ejecutes por ejemplo:

```
set.seed(2023)
```

No importa el número que elijas como semilla, lo que sí es fundamental que sea siempre el mismo antes de la ejecución de cada gráfico.